# Dropbox SDK for Ruby and not requiring reauthorization

Tags: ruby, dropbox

It seems like I must be missing something here. I'm working on a simple app and I'm starting with Dropbox's tutorial:

```
# Install this the SDK with "gem install dropbox-sdk"
require 'dropbox_sdk'

# Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developer website
APP_KEY     = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
APP_SECRET  = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
CODE        = 'QEL2VDUKRj4AAAAAAAAAAcBT_U9GoEvKF2UCXp3h4UA'

flow = DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect.new(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)
puts flow.start()
access_token, user_id = flow.finish(CODE)

client = DropboxClient.new(access_token)

file = open('working-draft.txt')
response = client.put_file('/magnum-opus.txt', file)
puts "uploaded:", response.inspect
```

The code only seems to work for one request (or at least one run of the script), and then I get an error:

```
E:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dropbox-sdk-1.6.2/lib/dropbox_sdk.rb:69:in `parse_response': invalid_grant (DropboxError)
```

What do I have to do in order to get this to work without authorizing every single time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store the access token somewhere and reuse it as much as you want.

To try this manually, just print out the value of `access_token` and then modify your code to just be:

```
access_token = '<value from previous run>'
client = DropboxClient.new(access_token)
```

Comment: I'm just supposed to skip the flow entirely aren't I? I think that's my mistake. I am storing the token, but I'm running the DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect.new line every time and that must be what's requiring me to reauthorize.

Comment: Yes, just skip the flow entirely, like in my code above. It looks like you're storing the authorization code, but you need to be storing the access token (the first thing returned from `flow.finish`).

Comment: From https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ruby: "The access token is all you'll need to make API requests on behalf of this user, so you should store it away for safe-keeping (even though we don't for this tutorial). By storing the access token, you won't need to go through these steps again unless the user reinstalls your app or revokes access via the Dropbox website."